# Changing ViewState after event requires additional refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate

I have an `Asp:ListBox` with `OnSelectedIndexChange="OnSIC"` and `AutoPostback="true"`.

I want to keep track of the selected index after the postback to show some data that depends on the index.

My idea is to save the selected index in `ViewState`.

```
protected void OnSIC(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["idx"] = listBox.SelectedIndex;
}
```

However, after the page is refreshed, `Page_Load` does not yet have the updated `ViewState["idx"]` value. An additional refresh is required to make `Page_Load` get the new index value.

I understand that postback events happen after `Page_Load`, so I tried moving the code that gets `ViewState["idx"]` in `Page_PreRender`, but I get the same behavior.

How can I correctly store the listbox's selected index value, after a `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event is fired, and use it on the very next page refresh (that happens because of the event postback)?

Comment: Why not simply use `listBox.SelectedIndex` everywhere instead of `ViewState["idx"]`?

Comment: Where on your page are you trying to consume the selected index of the list box?

Comment: @MichaelLiu: Because I'm filling the lists dynamically at page load. If I don't keep track of the selected index somewhere, it gets reset on refresh/postback. 
GiorgosBetsos: I have a second listbox I want to fill after an index is selected from the first one. I want the user to click an item from the first listbox, then a postback will happen, and the second listbox should be filled.